# Change image size of predefined UITableViewCell design "basic

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am currently creating a form using a normal `UITableView`. For the cells i choose the style "basic" in my Storyboard, which allows me to set an image to it. This image seems to have a set size of `52 x 52`. But i want it to be `26 x 26`. Is it possible without defining a custom `UITableViewCell` style?

Comment: in storyboard just set image constrain and give fix hight width

Comment: impossible for the predefined style it is greyed out

Comment: Are u using uiimageview? just give it fixed height + ratio then it will be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to subclass `UITableViewCell`. You can then adjust the frames of the `imageView` and the `textLabel` in `layoutSubviews`.

A much better solution, in my opinion, is not to use predefined styles at all and simply draw a prototype cell on the storyboard. You will have full control over the size of your image view.

Comment: But then you probably will _still_ need to subclass UITableViewCell so that you can refer to the image view.

Comment: Of course, unless you only need to configure the cells via storyboard (i.e. using static as opposed to prototyped cells)